# (null) is being printed while printing a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf, scanf

I  wrote a C program which takes a string input from user and prints it on the screen.

```
int main (void)
{
    char* string;
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("%s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

But the output was undesirable.

I gave input `foo`. Program printed out `(null)`. Can anyone explain Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* string;
```

This is just a pointer to a `char`. It doesn't point to any memory yet. You need to allocate memory for the characters that you want it to hold.

---

You can allocate memory using `malloc()`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *string;
    string = malloc(100); //string of length 100

    if(string == NULL){
        printf("Error\n");  //if malloc() fails
    }

    if((scanf("%99s", string)) != 1){ //if scanf() fails
        printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s\n",string);

    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, use an array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char string[100];

    if((scanf("%99s", string)) != 1){
        printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s\n",string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba, this is one of those times i feel we should have smiley support in SO comments.. Thanx :)

Comment: You should check `string` for `NULL` and replace **%s** with **%99s** in your second example.

Comment: @Michi, i just wanted to give him an allocation example wrt his code.

Comment: @Haris I do understand that, but if we do that, let's do it right. :)  [You should check scanf for errors too](http://ideone.com/9yrNDa).

Comment: @Haris You get a `+` for that :). Ad `exit(1);` if `malloc()` fails.

Answer (score 3):

You did not allocate memory to `string`. Thus, by writing into uninitiated pointer, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Before you use `string`, either you have to allocate memory dynamically using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family, or define `string` to be an array, like `char srting[32]` or something.

Also, FWIW, it is always better to limit your input size by the allocated memory, like

```
scanf("%31s", string);
```

to protect from buffer overflow in case of longer-than-expected input.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` doesn't allocate any memory for `string`; you need to do this yourself prior to calling the function. Else your program behaviour is *undefined*.

A simple way would be to refactor to `char string[100];` say, and *hope* that `scanf` doesn't attempt to read more than 99 characters plus the null terminator.

Later on, you'll realise that hoping is too much to ask, and will end up writing your own I/O functions.